# php foreach total number of item

Tags: php

Using php simple dom parser i have list of item, i want count how many item in that result.
IF i got 15 item i want display total as 15.

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$search = $_GET['search']; 
$html = file_get_html('http://mysite/'.$search.'.html');

foreach ( $html->find('div#song_html ') as $e ) {

  $title= $e->find('div', 2)->plaintext;
  $total=           //????? How can i Get total number of item????

 echo $title.'<br>'; 
 echo $total.'<br>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$total = count($html->find('div#song_html '));
```

Comment: Hei your first answer working fine... $total = count($html->find('div#song_html '));

Comment: Change it i will acsept your answer

Comment: Sorry, didn't was sure about the items you wanted to count. Just changed it back.